# Background image refuses to scale. Replaced with 400x800 placeholder

Tags: css, image, background

The background image on the website i'm working on (http://www.oatfoundry.com/) doesn't scale correctly for mobile devices. Everything else seems to work fine, but when the aspect ration gets below 537x542, the background image is replaced with a 400x800 grey placeholder. Any thoughts?

Comment: You'll have to show us your code for us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

There's this rule in your media.css file :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 520px) {

#home {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    color:#FFF;
    background:url('http://www.placehold.it/1400x800')50% 80% no-repeat scroll !important;
    background-position:center;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-attachment : fixed;  /* FIXED FOR IE */}
```

Notice the background is set to a placeholder when the screen is under 520px wide... I found this by watching the computed layout of the #home section within Firebug, while resizing the viewport in Firefox Responsive Design View, just so you know.